# My primary computer gets slower network speeds than the rest of my computers at house. Everything gets 220Mbps while mine gets 30

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, performance

I have already confirmed it was not my router, I plugged a different computer into the same CAT-6 I use for the problem computer and it got 220Mbps.

I've already run Avira and Malwarebytes scans and restarted my computer, I have a very tech-savvy guy at my side but he can't seem to figure it out.

when I was trying to download a game last night, it was running at >5Mbps. I have already removed all unnecessary item from my disk tray and I have no idea what else to do at this point.i have reinstalled network drivers, bought a new network card, did a clean boot, network safe mode restart, and a lot of other stuff.
Any suggestions?

My Windows computer specs are 16 GB RAM, Intel (R)Core(TM) i7-2600k CPU @ 3.30 gigahertz.

Comment: Slowed down _typing_? What's your CPU's usage% as shown by Task Manager?

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, try it while booting in Safe Mode with Networking.

Comment: 13% on cpu, 36% memory, 0% on disk and 0% on network

Comment: how do i go into safe mode?

Comment: Example [link](https://support.shaw.ca/t5/internet-articles/how-to-boot-your-computer-in-safe-mode-with-networking-windows/ta-p/5450).

Comment: Is it slowed down in word too? What about the search bar in file explorer?

Comment: no, i dont think so, its not all the time, it happens sometimes after ive been using it for a little while

Comment: and yes for everyones convenience i am on windows, thank you all in advance for your assistance

Comment: Check the duplex settings of your network card.  Most will default to auto.  Have seen some combinations where you need to set speed AND duplex manually.  An easy thing to test.

Comment: thank you all so much for your support, i have run everything imaginable but im also learning so much about my computer. i have run a clean boot, a network reset, bought a new external network card (the limit of which is a gig per second) and run countless anti malware searches. no dice. although, i do notice my computer running a bit faster. the search bar problems seem to have stopped,  no issues in word or anything like that. i will try the duplex speed as dave m suggested, im sixteen and this is my first real pc that wasnt a laptop, so i thank you all so much for your time and energy.

Comment: i did try the safe mode suggestion by harry mc, but that didnt seem to work. it did seem to bring me up the 35 or 36 megs tho, so thats progress.

Answer (score 0):

Please check at which speed is your network card connecting to your router. The Ethernet is 1Gb but it can connect at link speeds of 100Mb and 10Mb too.

Check as well you hard disk sanity (use a SMART tool). This can happen too if there are issues while writing to disk (depending on how you measure network speed).

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: Google for it, "how to check at which speed is my network card" and "download SMART tool".

Comment: my pc is saying i apparently have a limit of 100 mbps, but ive operated at more than double that before with the same exact equipment

Comment: that smells like wrong driver.

Comment: i deleted and reinstalled my network driver like twice, also thanks again for all ur help